# Assign label in new column based on quartile range of values

Tags: python, pandas, quartile

I'm attempting to label values based on a quartile range of one column in my dataset, but am having trouble synthesizing two steps. Here's a toy dataset below:

```
fruit   rating_store   rating_home    

apple   1.0            .8
pear    .8             .9
berry   .9             .4
tomato  .7             .5
orange  .3             .6
banana  .2             .4
...     ...            ...
```

First, I'm trying to identify the quartile range of `rating_home` which I can do with:

```
qrating_home = pd.cut(df['rating_home'], 4).value_counts().reset_index()
```

However, I'm now having trouble assigning labels (e.g., "low", "low_med", "high_med", "high") to the `qrating_home` range of values *in* the dataset. Desired output:

```
fruit   rating_store   rating_home   rating_home_quartile 

apple   1.0            .8            high
pear    .8             .9            high
berry   .9             .4            low
tomato  .7             .5            low
orange  .3             .6            low_med
banana  .2             .4            low
...     ...            ...
```

This post was very helpful but hardcoded the ranges: [How to categorize a range of values in Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677210/how-to-categorize-a-range-of-values-in-pandas-dataframe)
Because my dataset may change as more data comes in, I need to calculate the ranges each time that I run my code. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
df['rating_home_quartile'] = pd.cut(df['rating_home'], bins=4, 
                                     labels=['low', 'low_med', 'high_med', 'high'])
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to bucket your data in to quartiles. `pd.qcut` can do this easily for quartiles, quintiles, deciles, etc.

```py
df['rating_home_quartile'] = pd.qcut(df['rating_home'], q=4, labels=['low', 'low_med', 'high_med', 'high'])
```

- `q` is the number of quantiles
- `labels` is the corresponding quantile names; make sure it matches number of quantiles given to `q`