# How to flag a given value based on a range rule

Tags: python, algorithm, switch-statement

I've flags, each range of value has a flag.
for ex :

- value = 0 is D
- value > 0 and < 0.2 is C
- value >=0.2 and <=0.8 is B
- value > 0.8 is A

flag = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

```
def get_flag(value) : 
            if value == 0: return "D"
            elif value > 0.8: return "A"
            elif value <=0.8 and value >= 0.2: return "B"  
            else: return "C"
```

i think this implementation is annoying and not algorthmically pretty to see, any suggestions so i can get the correct index in python, i thought about modulo and div but values are floats between 0 and 1.

Comment: It depends on what is your input. If you're working with pandas dfs, maybe this is what you're looking for.  [pd.cut answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677210/how-to-categorize-a-range-of-values-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: What is the associated flag for *value == -1* ? In your implementation it would be 'C' but that doesn't fit with your description

Comment: @OldBill i normalize the data between 0 and 1, so i'm sure to not get any value <0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `elif` and `else` here, since `return` ends the execution of the function (so that lines after a `return` are not executed if the preceding `return` is triggered):

```
def get_flag(value) : 
    if value == 0: return "D"
    if value < 0.2: return "C"
    if value <= 0.8: return "B"
    return "A"
```

Answer (score 1):

Reorder your conditions:

```
def get_flag(value) : 
    if value == 0: return "D"
    elif value < 0.2: return "C"
    elif value <= 0.8: return "B"
    else: return "A"
```

It looks pretty clear to me what the ranges are now.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option to improve readability:

```
def get_flag(value):
    if value >= 0.8:
        return('A')

    elif value >= 0.2:
        return('B')
    
    elif value > 0:
        return('C')
    
    else:
        return('D')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same idea as @aa_nador (his answer has been deleted), store the separation points and flags in the list, and determine the index through binary search. Here, the second separation point is the next floating point number in the negative direction of 0.2 instead of 0.2 so that 0.2 can be distributed to index 2:

```
>>> seps = [0, math.nextafter(0.2, -math.inf), 0.8]
>>> flags = list('DCBA')
>>> {i / 10: flags[bisect.bisect_left(seps, i / 10)] for i in range(10)}
{0.0: 'D',
 0.1: 'C',
 0.2: 'B',
 0.3: 'B',
 0.4: 'B',
 0.5: 'B',
 0.6: 'B',
 0.7: 'B',
 0.8: 'B',
 0.9: 'A'}
```